# resizing a gridpane in square in main windows?

Tags: javafx

I am designing a Pentagon game in JAVAFX and I put a 6x6 gridpane as the main board.
Now when I resize the main window by dragging, I want this 6x6 gridpane to remain as the square (the shape should not change to a rectangle).

what can I use to solve it?

Comment: Can you post your code and a screen capture of your _Pentagon_ game that shows your problem?

Comment: my problem is solved by adding a pane and put gridpanes inside it.